# How do you give a page in the data folder access to the require function?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I wanted to open a tab from `main.js` so I did:

```
tabs.open(data.url("page.html"));
```

But how do I give the page that opens access to the `require` functions? I have a value stored in simple storage that I need to write to the page. I read something about using a content script that has access to the page, but that seems to only be for panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to look at content scripts docs, specifically 'Communicating with Content Scripts':

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/dev-guide/addon-development/web-content.html

It's a bit complicated, essentially the Addons SDK implements a way to send messages between your Addons code and scripts running in an html page.